# i am having batch file but it gives syntax error when using in windows 7

Tags: file, batch-file

```
@ echo off

move /y c:\program files (x86)\presst~1\Newsview\received\coreplus  \\edt_np\pti

@echo off

d:\sleep 30
d:\wire.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to "quote parameters containing separators"

```
move /y "c:\program files (x86)\presst~1\Newsview\received\coreplus"  \\edt_np\pti
```

Comment: What is the **/y** switch for?

Comment: @compo: `/y` for `move` suppresses the overwrite prompt

Comment: …but there isn't one, by default, in a batch file.

Comment: @Compo: OP's batch used it - or do you mean "it's undocumented" (It **is** documented)

Comment: @Magoo I think Compo means that (he believes) that the MOVE command in a batch file won't, by default, prompt for overwrite. He's wrong about that; it doesn't matter whether it's interactive or a batch file - if the destination file exists, MOVE will prompt for overwrite, unless that prompt is suppressed the way OP did.

Comment: I'm aware the OP used it, but as the question, title and tag all suggest batch file, and it is documented that the switch isn't required by default in that situation, then your answer doesn't need it either. No big deal, just an observation. @JeffZeitlin, _(what make you assume I'm male)_, no it's not my belief at all, the documentation believes it, I only made my comment based upon that documentation.

Comment: @Compo: quite correct. The `/r` switch makes no difference in batch. Interestingly, if the target is read-only, the prompt will occur from batch, whether or not the `/r` switch is used; the file will not be overwritten and a bogus "...duplicate filename..." message appears, regardless of response to the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a rough look:
Seems like you need to use some " for your paths. A space leads the programm to think that the next argument start but your arguments are not c:\program and files and (x86) etc. Instead it is one string "c:\program files (x86)\presst~1\Newsview\received\coreplus"